# Can I use a python decorator to preprocess input and postprocess output based on an input type?

Tags: python, overloading, decorator, typing

I have functions that can take either a `List` or a `str`. The return type should match the input type. E.g., if given a `str` the function should return a `str`.

This is a toy example to illustrate the point:

```
def swap_first_and_last(a: Union[List, str]) -> Union[List, str]:
    # Not in-place.
    STR = isinstance(a, str)
    a = list(a)

    a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]

    return "".join(a) if STR else a
```

This is an actual example:

```
def next_permutation(a: Union[List, str]) -> Union[List, str]:
    """
    Not in-place.
    Returns `None` if there is no next permutation
    (i.e. if `a` is the last permutation).
    The type of the output is the same as the type of the input
    (i.e. str input -> str output).
    """
    STR = isinstance(a, str)
    a = list(a)

    N = len(a)
    i = next((i for i in reversed(range(N-1)) if a[i] < a[i + 1]), None)
    if i is None:
        return None
    j = next(j for j in reversed(range(i+1, N)) if a[j] >= a[i])

    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    a[i + 1:] = reversed(a[i + 1:])

    return "".join(a) if STR else a
```

As you can see, only a few lines are dedicated to handling `str` input vs `List` input, namely:

```
    # preprocess
    STR = isinstance(a, str)
    a = list(a)
    
    # main logic
    ...
    
    # postprocess
    return "".join(a) if STR else a
```

Can I use a decorator to do this slight preprocessing and postprocessing?

Comment: Not exactly what you're after, but are you aware of the [`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) decorator in the `functools` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a decorator like this:

```
from typing import Union, List

def pre_and_post_processing(func):
    def inner(a: Union[List, str]) -> Union[List, str]:
        STR = isinstance(a, str)
        a = list(a)
        b = func(a)
        return "".join(b) if STR else b
    return inner   


@pre_and_post_processing
def swap_first_and_last(a: List) -> List:
    a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]
    return a


print(swap_first_and_last("asd"))  # -> dsa
print(swap_first_and_last(["asd", "ds", "sds"]))  # -> ['sds', 'ds', 'asd']
```

Note that the `swap_first_and_last` function now get and return a `List`.

Comment: Thanks! I like both solutions, but the advantage of this one over `singledispatch` is that one can define a single decorator (i.e. `@pre_and_post_processing`) and use it on several functions (i.e. on `swap_fist_and_last` and `next_permutation`. By contrast, it seems that with `singledispatch`, one has to do the `singledispatch` setup for each function.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @larsks suggestion, here is a way to use `singledispatch` on the @joseville toy example:

Example:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def swap_first_and_last(a: str) -> str:

    a = list(a)
    swap_first_and_last(a)
    return "".join(a)

@swap_first_and_last.register
def _(a: list) -> list:
    
    a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]
    return a

print(swap_first_and_last([1,2,3]))
print(swap_first_and_last("123"))
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 1]
321
```