# Managing pd.Series and pd.DatetimeIndex in a function simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a function meant to examine time-series data, usually obtained from a pandas dataframe. However, there are usually two ways to store this kind of data: the time-series can be stored in a column (in that case, it is a `pd.Series`, kind of), or serves as the dataframe's index. In that latter case, it's of type `pd.DatetimeIndex`.

I'd like my function to be used for both cases. The best I can think of is a transformation from index to series in the function itself, but that seems ugly: it requires checking the nature of the object and turning the index to a series and back (that I suppose costly in terms of performance.)

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import Union


def function(time_series: Union[pd.Series, pd.DatetimeIndex]): 
    """
    Do something
    :param time_series: my time-series, retrieved from a dataframe, and of type pd.Series, or pd.DatetimeIndex
    """
    
    series = time_series.copy()
    if isinstance(time_series, pd.DatetimeIndex):
        series = time_series.to_series()

    # do something on series

    if isinstance(time_series, pd.DatetimeIndex):
        return pd.DatetimeIndex(series)
    else: 
        return series
```

I think it's something the pandas library has to handle somehow. Does anyone have a hint ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply use **set_index()** to use the DateTime column as an index and then **reset_index()** when you then need it as a Column. No conversion is necessary. The 2 operations would together take a few mS for 100,000 rows.

Comment: Well, that seems a good approach. Maybe, I wanted my aquetsion to be a little wider. I have several functions, and making this pre-post processing seemed cumbersome. I am quite in the situation described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378555/can-i-use-a-python-decorator-to-preprocess-input-and-postprocess-output-based-on but I don't know if that seems a good approach.